# How to remove padding on Error text (TextInputLayout)?

Tags: android, xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/textinput_container_height"
app:errorEnabled="true"
app:errorTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small.ErrorStyle"
tools:hint="@string/ip_printers">

<EditText
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="-5dp"
app:errorTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small.ErrorStyle"
tools:text="1234567890" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

This my code. How I can remove padding to error text?
[img with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cc2PO.jpg)
[img with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6Hmi.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable padding on TextInputLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41403193/how-to-disable-padding-on-textinputlayout)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43541740/removing-textinputlayout-extra-top-padding

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34917677/textinputlayout-error-text-padding

Answer (score -2):

You have to remove this line

```
android:layout_marginStart="-5dp"
```

or

if you need that margin, please give in parentView -`android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout`

like

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/textinput_container_height"
app:errorEnabled="true"
app:errorTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small.ErrorStyle"
tools:hint="@string/ip_printers"
android:layout_marginStart="-5dp">
```

Answer (score -3):

`TextInputLayout` is a `LinearLayout`, so you should be able to specify a negative margin or padding, e.g.

```
android:layout_marginLeft="-2dp"    
android:layout_marginStart="-2dp"
```