# How to remove right padding/margin to a TextInputLayout prefix

Tags: android, padding, prefix, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

*TextInputLayout* prefix has a small but noticeable spacing to the subsequent text in the *TextInputEditText*.

In the following image, The first *www* is the prefix, the following are the regular text. I want to remove the spacing shown in the circle

[image]

My code:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/text_input_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:prefixText="www"
    app:prefixTextColor="@color/black">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/text_input_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41403193/how-to-disable-padding-on-textinputlayout

Comment: @SaifulSazib the edittext padding itself is fine, it's the prefix's right padding inside the edittext which is giving me headaches

Comment: This might help. create a custom class. https://rrohaill.medium.com/adding-a-prefix-to-textinputedittext-38a97a6bb12

Answer (score 2):

You can override the `material_input_text_to_prefix_suffix_padding` dimension in your `dimens.xml` file

Something like:

```
<dimen name="material_input_text_to_prefix_suffix_padding">0dp</dimen>
```

[image]